# Error "NOTARY_REASSIGNMENT_NOT_ALLOWED" when trying to send a document to be notarized

Tags: docusignapi

After following this [official API recipe](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-using-enotary-programmatically) in C#, I get the following error when I send my envelope

```
{
    "errorCode": "NOTARY_REASSIGNMENT_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "message": "Reassignment is not allowed for 'Sign with Notary', please change recipient types or disable the 'change signing' envelope settings."
}
```

If I send the transaction in draft mode and then go to the portal to notarize the document, I now get the below error :
[image]

Any ideas of what could be the issue here ? Am I missing a setting in my account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading @Inbar Gazit's insight and @Drew's answer, I made it work by adding the 2 below properties :

```
"AllowReassign":false
"EnableWetSign":false
```

If I didn't add EnableWetSign, then I would get the below error :

```
{
    "errorCode": "NOTARY_SIGN_ON_PAPER_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "message": "SignOnPaper is not allowed for 'Sign with Notary', please change recipient types or disable the 'sign on paper' envelope settings."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where you want to allow your signers to change the responsibility of who can sign (like basically you send me to something to sign and I send it to Bob to sign instead). With notarized documents DocuSign cannot allow this because the notary has to confirm who is the signer. You should change this option (disable it) if you want to use a notary recipient.

This can be done via C# Code:

```
    EnvelopeDefinition envelope = MakeEnvelope(signerEmail, signerName);
    envelope.AllowReassign = false;
```

From my blog post:

Next, open the Advanced Options pop-up and uncheck the options Allow recipient to sign on paper and Allow recipients to change signing responsibility. These two options are typically selected by default, but are not allowed when using eNotary.

[image]

Comment: So that has to be done manually and can't be done programmatically ?

Comment: You should have an EnvelopeDefinition envelope;   or some other variable like that. 
envelope.AllowReassign = false;

Answer (score 1):

In your EnvelopeDefinition, setting `allowReassign` to False should prevent this error from occurring.

At the account level, you can set Settings > Signing Settings > disable `Allow recipients to change signing responsibility` as well.